# Validate $_POST parameter as float or int

Tags: php, rest

I am writing a REST interface with PHP to submit and query data coming from a weather station. Windspeed/temperature/etc values come via POST request as float (e.g. 1.32) **unless** they are zero, in which case the single '0' digit is sent.

I have written the following code to verify input values:

```
    if (is_numeric($params['wind']))
{
    if (!filter_var($params['wind'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION, $windLimit))
    {
        throw new Exception('WIND (wind) WRONG VALUE TYPE [received '.$params['wind'].'].');
    }
}
else
{
    throw new Exception('WIND (wind) WRONG TYPE [received '.$params['wind'].'].');
}
```

which works well for non-zero values, but fail verification when exactly 0.
Is there a specific filter to be used in filter_var() when value can both be integer or float?

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow for zero values use `=== FALSE` (i.e strictly equal to false):

```
if (filter_var(...) === FALSE)
{
    throw new Exception('WIND (wind) WRONG VALUE TYPE [received '.$params['wind'].'].');
}
```